# Two threads, one object

Tags: python, multithreading, hid, hidapi

I'm writing a Linux driver for a USB HID device in Python. The device has two ways it sends data, both of which are needed: feature reports (synchronous) and input reports (asynchronous). Using the hidapi Cython library I have only one instance of the device to work with, but I need to set up a listener for hid.read() that will run constantly AND allow synchronous methods to be called at will by the application to send feature reports.

Currently I have the listener in one thread and the synchronous calls in another. When I run the program, my synchronous calls are not happening, though they work fine if I never start the listener; so it appears the listener thread is taking over.

Below is the troubling piece of code:

**app.py**

```
# app.py
import threading
import time
import myhiddriver

# Code that sets mydevice

class Reader:
  def start(self, device):
    self.requests = myhiddriver.DeviceRequest(device)
    # Wait a bit before firing, for testing
    time.sleep(3)
    self.requests.request_swipe_card()

  def start_listener(self, device):
    self.listener = myhiddriver.DeviceListener(device)

reader = Reader()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=reader.start, args=(mydevice,))
thread1.daemon = True
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=reader.start_listener, args=(mydevice,))
thread2.daemon = True
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# Keep this puppy running
while True:
  pass
```

**myhiddriver.py**

```
import threading

LOCK = threading.Lock()

class DeviceRequest:
  def __init__(self, device):
    # Lock it up first
    LOCK.acquire()
    self.device = device
    LOCK.release()

  def request_swipe_card(self):
    # Lock this up too
    LOCK.acquire()
    self.device.set_feature_report(insert data here)
    LOCK.release()

class DeviceListener:
  def __init__(self, device):
    # Lock me up
    LOCK.acquire()
    self.device = device
    self.start_listener()
    LOCK.release()

  def start_listener(self):
    while True:
      # Should I be locking this up?
      LOCK.acquire()
      data = self.device.read(255)
      LOCK.release()
      if data:
        print data
      else:
        pass
```

**My Question: Why is my synchronous call (request_swipe_card) not following through? Or, how can I better architect this to have an endless listener AND the ability to make synchronous calls on the same object?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the looks of the code, it is because you are locking it up

> When the state is unlocked, acquire() changes the state to locked and
>   returns immediately. When the state is locked, acquire() blocks until
>   a call to release() in another thread changes it to unlocked

here is the problem:

```
class DeviceListener:
  def __init__(self, device):
    LOCK.acquire() # first you lock it up
    self.device = device
    self.start_listener()
    LOCK.release()

  def start_listener(self):
    while True: # because of the loop, the lock wouldn't get release even if the LOCK below doesn't exist
      LOCK.acquire() # it end up blocking here and oops, it locked up xD 
      data = self.device.read(255) # so it wouldn't be able to read here
      LOCK.release()
      if data:
        print data
      else:
        pass
```

and when the `request_swipe_card` end up being call in the other thread, it end up blocking there too

```
  def request_swipe_card(self):
    LOCK.acquire() # right here xD
    self.device.set_feature_report(insert data here)
    LOCK.release()
```

Comment: I wound up going in the direction of multiprocessing since I have the luxury of multiple cores, but this makes sense. Thanks!